# Reading Time Language

Tags: multi-language, addons, localization

I installed the Reading Time module from:
https://github.com/EllisLab/Reading-Time

But there is a problem. It outputs the time based on the EE language config text as:
**is about 5 minutes**

Or
**is 1 one minute**

This a problem on pages with different languages. Is there a way to force a different language on the variable or the template page? EE can use different language files but how do I specify this for visitors that are not logged in? I need to force to use a different locale on specific templates or the exp variable.

Answer (score 0):

That plugin is not built to be multi-language-friendly, so you'd need to modify it to match the currently-loaded locale (based on whichever method you've chosen to set the current language).

Comment: That is my actual question. How to specify the language on a page in order to be able to modify the code I need to tell it the locale to use.

Comment: That's a larger question - there are many approaches you can take to multi-lingual sites in EE. [Here's a question which has many answers discussing many of them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196903/multi-language-approaches-with-expressionengine)

Comment: I'm not asking how to make a multi-lingual site. My question is if there is a tag or variable to put in a page that instructs EE (hello, this locale is English, or Hello, this locale is French). The plugin is using the default English text because EE has English as default, all text related to date and other functions are on that EE file on installation, you can install additional files. But what I need to do is just tell the plugin to use a different language ( different file). This is possible with logged in users since they have a profile on which to set a language, but not with visitors.

Comment: Like I said, the way in which you'll need to modify the plugin file to meet your needs will all depend on which method you've chosen to determine and set the language of your visitors.